# Any way to set a private ip within vpc?

Tags: amazon-ec2, chef, amazon-vpc

I've tried using the **--private_ip_address** but nothing. Anyone knows if there is an option to set up a specific ip address inside of a vpc? I don't want to setup an elastic one. I have a vpn connection so I can access it. but it is important to my network configuration to have a known ip for my servers.
Is there any way to set it up?
I know that I can create the server and then use knife, this is what I'm doing now, just wondered if there is a way to do that fully from the command line.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Well, this option exists, just needed to take a look at the source, and I wasn't far off.
--private-ip-address IP-ADDRESS will get you there.